# Napili template Report chart - Report not visible

Tags: community, lightning, napili, report-chart, lightning-community

I have created a community using napili template. I have added a page with the report chart component, and added a report from the public folder to it. However, the reports are visible in the preview, but cannot be viewed on the page when I open it using the url. What changes should I make in the settings to resolve this issue?

I have created a permission set to allow the assignees to view reports in the public folder. I am getting the following error while assigning this permission set to the community users.

[image]

Comment: Is this visibility a problem for the system admin or as a community user?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a permission set with only the 'Create and Customise Reports', 'Edit Reports', 'Run Reports' and 'Report Builder' permissions for the Community users as they have the Customer Community Plus licence.

The users will also need to be granted access to the folders that the relevant reports and dashboards are held in.

From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_reporting_external_users_report_mgmt.htm&type=0)

> External User Permissions Needed to Create and Edit Reports
>   To create, customize, and delete reports in a personal folder:  “Create and Customize Reports”
>   AND
>   “Report Builder”
>
> To create, customize and delete their own reports in a privately
>   shared folder with Viewer access: “Edit My Reports” AND “Report
>   Builder”
>
> Blockquote

To export report data:  “Export Reports”

> You can give permission to create and edit reports to all role-based
>   external users with licenses such as Customer Community Plus and
>   Partner Community. You can also give permission to all legacy
>   role-based portal licenses such as Customer Portal and Gold Partner.
>
> Partner and customer users can’t create, edit, or view reports in the Unfiled Public Reports folder.